# Updating a ASP HiddenField in a MVC 4 controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, hidden-field

In my view, I have defined a simple asp:HiddenField as follows:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnUserRole" runat="server" />
```

Now, I have my RedirectToAction defined as this

```
if (Something)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminView", new { UserRole = "Admin" });
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminView", new { UserRole = "Inquiry" });
        }
```

In the Controller, I want to assign the hidden field defined above to the value of the UserRole. The idea over here is to hide the Update buttons present in the view. I plan on doing the same in the jQuery(document).ready function. I appreciate any help or any alternate approach that y'all might have.

```
 public class AdminViewController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /AdminView/

    #region Index With Roles

    public ActionResult Index(String UserRole)
    {
        if (UserRole == "Admin")
        { 
            //ToDo: Update the hidden field "hdnUserRole"

        }
        else if (UserRole == "Inquiry")
        { 

        }

        return View();
    }

 }
```

Comment: Why are you using classic asp tags in a mvc app?

Comment: Yes, completely wrong approach.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I am wrong because my approach isn't working. Please tell me how else do I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at what you're trying to achieve, I *think* you want some general `Admin` actions, a general one and another called `Inquiry` and they should use the same `View`. So, how about instead of your routes being...

```
AdminView/Index/Admin
AdminView/Index/Inquiry
```

...you use something like:

```
Admin/Index
Admin/Inquiry
```

So your redirects will now look like:

```
return ReidrectToAction("Index", "Admin")
return RedirectToAction("Inquiry", "Admin")
```

From here you have two approaches. If the entire page is the same apart from hiding a few buttons, you can return the exact same `View`. Otherwise I would put your shared component in a partial `View` and have a page for each `Action` which both use the shared component. I'll describe the first approach to get you going. So you could have two actions that both return the same `View`:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Admin/Index

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Source = "admin";
        return View("Index");
    }

    //
    // GET: /Admin/Inquiry

    public ActionResult Inquiry()
    {
        ViewBag.Source = "inquiry";
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

I've assumed the `View` is called `Index` and is located in `Views/Admin`.

Then in your JavaScript on page load, you could do whatever you want with the string we assigned to `ViewBag.Source` in the controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var context = '@ViewBag.Source'; // will be 'admin' or 'inquiry'
</script>
```

However with what you're trying to achieve, you might be best just doing it in your razor.

```
@if(ViewBag.Source == "admin") // I came from Admin/Index!
{
    <button type="button">Update</button>
}
```

If you still want a hidden field on your page you can use:

```
@Html.Hidden("Source", (string)ViewBag.Source) // must cast
```

which would render the following html:

```
<input id="Source" name="Source" type="hidden" value="admin">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. This solution is way cleaner than what I was looking at.